QGIS DEM to elevation Points, pixels not centred
I have a DEM which I'm trying to convert into a point layer in QGIS. I used the raster pixels to points tool, which seemed to work, except that the points are not in the centre of the DEM pixels. They are all off in the north east corner of each pixel.

All layers and project are in the same coordinate system (GDA2020 Geographic EPSG:7844). How can I get these pixels into the middle of each pixel, short of manually shifting them?

Please edit your question to specify what coordinate system (GDA 2020 geographic? GDA 2020 MGA? GDA 2020 Albers? GDA 2020 NSW Lambert...?). An EPSG code would be good.

I can't reproduce in QGIS 3.36 and trying a variety of GDA2020 coordinate systems.  Are you sure you're pointing the tool at the correct raster layer?

It looks like MGA94 to MGA2020 shift, try setting your canvas to 'unknown' and see if they line up properly when there is no transformation, if it's a transformation/incorrect CRS issue then the points will locate in the centre of the cell properly.

I am new to this website, is this how I reply to comments? user2856, I have done as you asked. It is geographic. Yes, I have selected the correct Raster Layer. The points are all in the pixels, and they have sampled the values of the raster correctly. They are just not in the center of the pixel. I ended up just manually editing the points, dragging them into the center of the pixels. Is this likely to be an issue?

I have made an error. Before running the pixels to points tool, I clipped the raster by a mask layer to reduce processing. The clipped raster had a different cell placement to the original, which is why the points were offset from the centre of the pixels
